# Typescript issue while mapping through array from antd form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, antd

I'm creating a simple webpage on React + TS with ant design library and I have a problem with types in form component.
I created an array to map through them and render form.

https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-mountain-vb1b0e?from-embed

That looks an element in array which gives me an error.

```
const FormItems = [
  // {              
  //   name: 'name',
  //   label: 'Imię/ firma',
  //   rules: { required: true },  <----- this element is good
  //   inputType: <Input />,
  // },
  {
    name: 'email',
    label: 'Email',
    rules: { type: 'email', required: true }, <---- this element giving an error
    inputType: <Input />,
  },
];
```

ERROR / / /

```
Type '{ type: string; required: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'Rule'.
  Type '{ type: string; required: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'ArrayRule'.
    Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"array"'.ts(2322)
```

And this error occurs in this fragment of code:

```
{FormItems.map((item) => (
          <Form.Item
            name={['user', item.name]}
            label={item.label}
            rules={[item.rules]} <--- item.rules are underlined
          >
            {item.inputType}
          </Form.Item>
        ))}
```

Comment: Form.Item is just wrapper for https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-field-form#rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antd provide type definition for rules props. You can import it like this:

`import { Rule } from 'antd/es/form';`

Now you can define the type of your FormItems List like this:

```
import { Rule } from 'antd/es/form';
import { ReactNode } from 'react';

type FormItemsListType = {
    name: string;
    label: string;
    rules: Rule[];
    inputType: ReactNode;
};

const FormItems: FormItemsListType[] = [
    {
        name: 'email',
        label: 'Email',
        rules: [{ type: 'boolean', required: true }],
        inputType: <Input />
    }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

The prop expects a `string`, not a `boolean` value, [consult the documentation here](https://ant.design/components/form#components-form-demo-dynamic-rule:%7E:text=to%20ref%20here-,string,-validateTrigger) and [here](https://github.com/yiminghe/async-validator#type), however, I am unable to reproduce this error, if possible, please try reproducing it on [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/) or a similar service.

```
  {
    name: "email",
    label: "Email",
    rules: {
      type: 'boolean',
      required: true
    },
    inputType: <Input />
  }
```

Comment: Oh yes, of course it's need a string. That was for testing purpose. Edited post about that and add sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-mountain-vb1b0e?from-embed